# Replace or delete a character from row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Replace or delete a character from the row in pandas
I tried using

| srno. | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | #abc |
| 2 | bc#d |

'df = df.replace{Name:('#','', regex=True)}'

i want to delete # from name
giving me an error

| srno. | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | bcd |

df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('#','', regex=True)

delete the other records

| srno. | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | #abc |
| 2 | NAN |

Comment: Can you add some sample data to question?

Comment: For me working correct, what is `print (df['Name'].head(10).tolist())` ?

Answer (score 0):

If row label is `Name` use:

```
df.loc['Name'] = df.loc['Name'].str.replace('#','', regex=True)
```

If `Name` is column name use:

```
df = df.replace({'Name':{'#':''}}, regex=True)
print (df)
  srno. Name
0      1  abc
1      2  bcd
```

---

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('#','', regex=True)
print (df)
   srno. Name
0      1  abc
1      2  bcd
```

Answer (score 0):

Using apply-lambda;

```
df["Name"] = df["Name"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("#",""))
```